# Using IF() With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a PHP script which runs a MySQL query.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
          VALUES('$val1', '$val2')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2= IF(IS NOT NULL '$val1', 'test', 'col2)";
```

Here is what I am trying to do:
Col1 is the primary key.  If there is a duplicate, it checks to see if the insert value for col2 is null.  If not, it will update with the value, otherwise the value will stay the same.

This insert fails.  When I try to run it manually in sqlyog (inserting actual values in place of variables), I get the following error:
Error Code: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NOT NULL.....'

I have checked the MySQL reference manual for the IS NOT NULL comparison operator (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null), and also for the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and believe I am using both correctly, but obviously that is not the case.

What am I doing wrong?

For reference, I am using MySQL 5 and the script is running on a RHEL5 server.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The syntax `IS NOT NULL column` is wrong. Correct: `column IS NOT NULL`. I'm not sure what this `'test'` is about. You say that you want to either update the column or keep it as it is.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
          VALUES('$val1', '$val2')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = IF('$val2' IS NOT NULL, '$val2', col2)";
```

which can also be written as:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
          VALUES('$val1', '$val2')
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            col2 = COALESCE( VALUES(col2), col2)";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  Also, the 'test' value was an oversight; this was a value that I was using for col2 when testing, and forgot to remove it.